# How to select one column in Datatable using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

I found one solution is to browse each row in the table. But is there a better solution?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table tr').each(function(){
        $(this).find('td').eq(2).css('background-color', 'green');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you give more detail what do you want to do.  Secondly,Your title is about selecting a column but your sayin >'I found one solution is to browse each row in the table', Are you trying to get rows or columns?

Comment: I want to insert css for any column in the data table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use `each()` method.Just use jquery selector

`$('tr td:first-child').css('background','#07C');`

or for nth column

```
$('tr td:nth-child(2)').css('background','#07C');
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('tr td:nth-child(2)').css('background','#5ae');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>first Column</td>
    <td>second Column</td>
    <td>third Column</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>first Column</td>
    <td>second Column</td>
    <td>third Column</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>first Column</td>
    <td>second Column</td>
    <td>third Column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```